# python match dynamic keys in a dictionary and if they match get value of other key in the same dictionary

Tags: python

I have a stream of dictionary items like this

```
{
    "KafkaBrokerStats[2].groupName": "emaas-target-topic-CloudDatabaseResources-id-dev-appshףard1-apps-OPS-SYSEMS_T_1018-consumer-group-EMaaS-Target-Property-ODS-Loader",
    "KafkaBrokerStats[2].currentKafkaOffset": 4,
    "KafkaBrokerStats[2].currentKafkaBacklog": 0,
    "KafkaBrokerStats[2].topicName": "target_topic",
    "KafkaBrokerStats[2].currentKafkaQueueSize": 4
}
```

This is what i am trying to achieve.

Check if KafkaBrokerStats.*topicName and KafkaBrokerStats.*groupName matches a given set of values, then i need to retrieve the value of KafkaBrokerStats.*currentKafkaBacklog

Have been trying multiple ways of doing this, but unable to achieve. Can anyone please help

Comment: could you provide your best approach you have so far?

Comment: Along with a description of what it is doing incorrectly (including stack trace if you're getting an exception).